# Representation of topological groups

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, topological-groups

I am looking for a good book of topological representation.
I have a very good insight of representation theory of finite groups, and I want to explore topological representations.

I saw a book by Kirillov, and it looks quite good, but it involves category theory, which I know nothing...

Comment: Are you interested in arbitrary topological groups, or some special kind (ie, Lie, algebraic,...)?

Comment: I am interested in arbitrary topological groups, and I have a particular interest in representations of direct limits of finite groups.

Comment: In that case, I think you will find it very hard to avoid category theory (and it will probably not benefit you to avoid it).

Comment: I see... Can you recommend me some good introductory book for representations and categorys?

Comment: There is a classical Lev Pontrjagin’s book “Continuous groups” or “Topological groups” (original is in Russian, but [there exists an English translation](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=D50OAAAAQAAJ&redir_esc=y) too). If I remember it right, I read a bigger part of the book and encountered no references to category theory. This was good for me, because usually I do not think in notions of this theory. :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should learn about Haa rmeasure, and measure theory on locally compact groups in general. Here, I enjoyed reading Deitmar-Echterhoff "Principles of Harmonic analysis".

Then, you feel the need to supplement this with structure theory. This is also partly covered by that book, but I really mean considering locally compact groups locally as projective limits of Lie groups. I explain this in the fourth chapter of my thesis with references: http://ediss.uni-goettingen.de/bitstream/handle/11858/00-1735-0000-000D-F074-7/palm.pdf?sequence=1

The Standard reference here is Deane Montgomery and Leo Zippin, Topological transformation groups.

Having understood all this, you might want to specify on which vector spaces and with what kind of representations you might want to work then.

There are many general theorem for unitary representation due to Mackey, which generalize the most important results of the finite group case such as the definition of induction, Frobenius reciprocity, Schurs lemma, Maschke decomposition, induction-restriction formulas and group extensions. Rac For finite groups, all complex representations are unitary.

I like Asim O. Barut and Ryszard Raczka, Theory of group representations and applications for this.

**As a starting point, you should start with compact groups and understand the Peter-Weyl theorem pretty well.**